# Column Person/group is empty SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

In a Workflow (created with SPD) i want to test if the column Person/group is empty but SPD only proposes: "is equal" or is different" So how can i translate **"Is empty"** in a condition. Is there a value like in an approval workflow (16=approved) and (2=pending)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the people field empty by getting the UserId or LoginName or Email. If these values are empty then people field is empty.

**Get UserId Value**

[image]

**Check people field is empty**[image]

Comment: If it answers your question mark as an answer it helps others to refer.

Comment: This results in a suspended workflow for me ...